# in bash how to put extglobed file names into array?

Tags: regex, bash, extglob

I knew I can do `arr=(*.log)` to get all *.log files into arr. But when I try extglob with more complex pattern it seems fail:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob extglob; x=([a-z][0-9].+([0-9]).*.gz); echo "${x}"; shopt -u nullglob extglob;
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

however without the extglob pattern `+(match)` it works:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob extglob; x=([a-z][0-9].[0-9][0-9].*.gz); echo "${x}"; shopt -u nullglob extglob;
v2.29.2.tar.gz
```

any suggestion?

Comment: It works well on my environment: `bash-4.4.20`. BTW you will need to say
`echo "${x[@]}"` to print array elements. `echo "${x}"` just prints `"${x[0]}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to dig for it a bit, but the [bash wiki says](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob):

> `extglob` changes the way certain characters are parsed. **It is necessary to have a newline (not just a semicolon) between `shopt -s extglob` and any subsequent commands to use it.**

Split your sequence of commands up into multiple lines and it should work:

```sh
shopt -s nullglob extglob
x=([a-z][0-9].+([0-9]).*.gz)
printf "%s\n" "${x[@]}"
shopt -u nullglob extglob
```